# Nonhamiltonian graphs whose complements are nonhamiltonian?

Tags: graph-theory

Nonhamiltonian graphs whose complements are nonhamiltonian? I thought of the stars K_(1,n), and also P_4 since it is self-complementary.

There must be loads of examples. Can anyone give further examples?

Comment: $K_{m,n}$ and $K_{m,n}-e$ where $m\ne n.$

Comment: The self-complementary graph of order $5$ which is not $C_5.$

Comment: $K_{m,n}-S$ where $1\lt m\lt n$ and $S$ is any set of pairwise adjacent edges in $K_{m,n}.$

Comment: Any non-bipartite ones?

Comment: Besides the one I mentioned in my second comment? A self-complementary graph of order $5.$ Vertices $a,b,c,d,e,$ edges $ab,bc,cd,de,bd.$

Comment: Start with any graph $G.$ Choose a vertex $w\in V(G).$ Add two new vertices $u,v,$ an edge $uv,$ and edges $vx$ for all $x\in V(G)\setminus\{w\}.$ Call the resulting graph $H.$ The graph $H$ is not Hamiltonian because $u$ is a vertex of degree $1$ in $H$, and its complement $\bar H$ is not Hamiltonian because $v$ is a vertex of degree $1$ in $\bar H.$

Comment: Yes any graph having vertices of degree n-1 and 1 is not hamiltonian "either way". Thanks.

Comment: ...or connected and co-connected